# Frame Drum Over-Stretch

Tags: drums

I have a Synthetic skin 20" Remo Frame Drum and it seems that I have over-tightened one side on one occasion resulting in a sort of wave in the drum.

I have tried loosening everything and starting again evenly several times, however, the side that was over-stretched still has a light wave through it that affects the sound of the whole drum.

Have I ruined skin on this instrument or is there a way I can repair this?

Thank you kindly for help & advice.

Answer (score 2):

Neck on line here. It may well be ruined as it is,. If it was mine, I'd loosen the tension but still keep it sounding - not too flappy - and use a hair drier or gentle heat gun to 'brush' out the kink, tightening gently on the way. Obviously not hot enough to melt or distort the skin. I've never tried it, but it's worth a try. Worst case scenario, throw it away, which is what will probably have happened in the absence of any other solution.

Comment: If you remove the skin from the drum, will it lay flat on a table without showing the "wave"? If not, throw it away - you have permanently over-stretched it, and there is no way to reverse that.

Answer (score 0):

Take the head off, rotate it 90 or 180 degrees. Then re-tension it by counting turns of the key. This should seat the head more correctly. The hair dryer trick may help and it shouldn't do any harm